# Very slow when rviz the kinect

Tags: kinect, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am using ROS hydro for kinect. When I use rviz to show the point clouds (unregistered and registered), the window turns very slow. The display can response even two or three seconds. Could anyone give me some suggestions to fix this problem? Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147131/very-slow-when-rviz-the-kinect/) by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [byeongkyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4428/byeongkyu/) on 2014-04-01**:
Can I know your machine specification? Graphic card performance is very important to view point cloud.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-01**:
Could you explain more detail? For example, with multi machine or with single machine? In case of multi machine, we can guess a problem on network. In case of single machine, we can guess a problem on graphic card as Mr. byeongkyu says.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
Also, did you compile rviz from source, or did you install it with apt?

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-04-02**:
@byeongkyu @Ken_in_JAPAN @demmeln Hi guys, thanks for you help. I am using single machine for rviz, and rviz is installed with hydro by default. I think it is installed with apt.

The computer's detailed information:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU U 540 @ 1.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~1.2GHz
Memory: 8192MB RAM

Display:
Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics
Chip Type: Intel(R) HD Graphics (Core i5)
DAC Type: Internal

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
@pinocchio: Installing from apt should be ok. If installing from source, you might get bad performance if your forget to set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Release. Not sure if this should be faster on your machine.

**Comment by [byeongkyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4428/byeongkyu/) on 2014-04-02**:
@pinocchio: It is recommend that upgrade your graphic card, and set your cpufreq to performance mode.

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2014-07-21**:
Have you solved this problem? My computer slows down the same when I display the point cloud in rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most likely cause is that you're not using hardware accelerated video drivers.  Rviz works best with nVidia graphics cards and the propriety driver.  My guess is that you're using software rendering (as opposed to taking advantage of the hardware on the GPU), and that this is what's causing the slow-down. I'd suggest that you make sure you're using hardware-accelerated video drivers, and see if that helps.

The best long-term solution, though, is probably to switch to an nVidia video card.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1